# Grails - external database controllers and domains

Tags: mysql, grails, controller, dns

I am new to Grails. I use my external mysql database. Do I have to make Grails domain classes for tables in my database (copy my database into domain model), or can I make controllers and views just for my external mysql tables without making domain classes?

Thank you for answers.

Answer (score 1):

No you effectively mock the database tables in your domains.

In fact, if you build your domains first, they will automatically build your tables for you; many people find this the easier way as if you have a pre-existing database, you have to match the constraints PERFECTLY to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

There is no requirement that you must use GORM with Grails. You can in fact just use the classes and such from the `groovy.sql` package and interact with your database directly using SQL and 'GroovyRowResult' instead of domain classes.

However, if you don't use GORM you also lose a lot of scaffolding (e.g. to create the controllers and views) because you have no domain modeled.

Answer (score 1):

Its better to declare your domain in class which could be related to database.

user domain class

```
class User {

    Long id
    String name

    static mapping = {
        table 'user'  //here user is database table name

        version false
        id column: 'id', generator: 'increment'
        name column: 'name'
    }

    static constraints = {
        id(nullable: true)
        name(nullable: false)
    }
}
```

you can use scaffolding in controller to generate CRUD as well like

```
class UserController {

    static scaffold = User
    def index() {
        def userList = User.list()
        [userList: userList]
    }
}
```

Without declaring your domain class you will get error to execute query from database in controller.